# Convertion UTM to google lat lon Proj4s

Tags: javascript, proj4js, utm

I don't know how to convert coordinates from utm to google lat lon using this library.

I have imported this:

```
  <script src="javascript/lib/proj4js-combined.js"></script>
  <script src="javascript/lib/defs/GOOGLE.js"></script>
  <script src="javascript/lib/util/MGRS.js"></script>
```

And now I am using this example:

```
 <script>
    console.log("hola");
    var utm = "+proj=utm +zone=32";
    var wgs84 = "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs";
    console.log("prueba");
    console.log(new Proj4js.Proj(utm,wgs84,[434306.32460000,4813243.12520000]));

</script>
```

I am having this error:

```
GET http://myurl/maps/javascript/lib/defs/+PROJ=UTM%20+ZONE=32.js 404 (Not Found)            proj4js-combined.js:439

GET http://spatialreference.org/ref//+PROJ=UTM%20+ZONE=32/proj4js/ 404 (NOT FOUND)        proj4js-combined.js:439

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function         proj4js-combined.js:743
```

Where is my error?

Answer (score 0):

use `proj4(utm,wgs84,[434306.32460000,4813243.12520000])` instead